# Node-ffi Bindings to An array of NULL terminated C strings, but got `Segmentation fault: 11`

Tags: c++, node.js, binding, node-ffi

I am using Node-ffi to write a Node bindings for [MITIE](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE). But I got problem,

The argument of a function is `char**`: An array of NULL terminated C strings, like this:

```
int run (char** tokens)
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<std::string> words;
        for (unsigned long i = 0; tokens[i]; ++i)
            words.push_back(tokens[i]);

        return 1;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And this is what I did use ffi:

```
const ffi = require('ffi');
const ArrayType = require('ref-array');

const StringArray = ArrayType('string')

const test = ffi.Library('test', {
  'run': [ 'int', [StringArray] ]
});

test.run(['a', 'b']);
```

But I got: `Segmentation fault: 11`.

I uploaded the sample code to [this repo](https://github.com/alvinhui/node-ffi-testing).

And in this repo you also can see I have wrote a Python bindings by [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), It runs well.

Here is my operating environment:

- npm@3.10.10
- node@7.10.0
- darwin x64 17.0.0
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- macOS 10.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly terminate token array with NULL:

```
const ffi = require('ffi');
const ArrayType = require('ref-array');
const ref = require('ref');

const StringArray = ArrayType('string')

const test = ffi.Library('test', {
  'run': [ 'int', [StringArray] ]
});

console.log(test.run(['a', 'b', ref.NULL])); // -> 2
```

Comment: thanks! It's helpful!But there was a lot of work I needed to do, so I decided to use Node C++ Addon to write a bindings wrap.